# Lambda function with both if and for loop

Tags: python

I am learning lambda funciton. Is there any way to rewrite the test_regex function with lambda in one line?

```
data=['AUD.TR.....1,000.00\n', '  10   200    HEADING\n', '  ']
regex={
    'key': '^([A-Z]){3}\.[A-Z]{2}\.*.*\\n$',
    'head': '^\s*[0-9]*\s*[0-9]*\s*[A-Z]*\\n$'  
      }

def test_regex(string):
    for j in regex:
        if re.match(regex[j], string):
            return j
    else:
        return None

print(list(map(test_regex, data)))
```

Comment: This line should work:
`test_regex = lambda string: next((j for j in regex if re.match(regex[j], string)), None)
`
Try out, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this in one line, but you don't need a lambda expression to do so.

```
def test_regex(string):
    return next((j for j in regex if re.match(regex[j], string)), None)
```

`next` returns the first value of `j` for which `re.match(regex[j], string)` succeeds. `next` returns `None` if the generator never produces a value.

Answer (score 0):

This line will work:

```
test_regex = lambda string: next((j for j in regex if re.match(regex[j], string)), None)
```

(You could, however, write the function itself in a single line, but that is not the same and not what you asked for.)